# What's the difference between 'docker save' and 'docker image save'?

Tags: docker

*From the documentation:*

**docker save**

> Description: Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)

Usage `docker save [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]`

**docker image save**

> Description: Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)

Usage `docker image save [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]`

Do they have the same behaviour or are there subtle differences depending on which one is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are same. Some frequently used commands have shorter aliases under `docker` subcommand.

Answer (score 2):

It's like `docker ps` and `docker container ls`, the same command but shorter alias.

Docker helper:

```
docker --help | grep save
//and 
docker image --help | grep save

//returns the same info.
-- Save one or more images to a tar archive (streamed to STDOUT by default)
```